# Tell me how to set automatic Ping in my Next.js website

Tags: next.js, ping

Please tell me how to set automatic Ping on pingomatic.com in my Next.js website https://www.mobileinfo.com.bd I want it when I post new content and then automatically send ping.

Advance thanks

I want to anyone tell me it is possibel to do this sysytem in my website